# Is there a way to block SVN commits unless they have a certain description in the commit description window using a hook?

Tags: svn, hook, pre-commit-hook, svn-hooks

I want to stop developers from committing unless they reference a ticket in the message field of their SVN commit.  for example, it should read something like "see ticket #999 - (description of change)" and if they don't have that formatting, it will stop the commit.  Is this possible with a hook and if so, how would I code that?

Comment: I don't want to sound mean, but have you tried searching the web for "Subversion Pre-Commit Hook"? This sort of requirement is a _common_ use for hook scripts.

Comment: I have done some searching for it but haven't been able to find what I need.

Comment: Then you may want to update your post linking to what you _have_ been able to find and explain _why_ it doesn't meet your needs. If you are hoping to receive help from Stack Overflow, the best way is to show that you have tried to solve the problem on your own and are stuck. Simply asking for help without showing what you have tried a.) Looks like you are just looking for someone else to solve your problems and b.) Doesn't give any potential helpers anywhere to start from.

Comment: check this question

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10381572/getting-log-message-from-svnlook-via-windows-batch/10456333#10456333