# Windows SVN hook which looks for a certain word in the comment

Tags: tortoisesvn

I am trying to implement a pre-commit subversion hook which looks for a pattern in the commit comment? Any pointers on how to do this? Like whenever someone tries to check in a file, I want to look for the word 'ABCD' in the comment they have entered along with forcing them to enter a comment. I found a similar question here [Is there a way to block SVN commits unless they have a certain description in the commit description window using a hook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9574885/is-there-a-way-to-block-svn-commits-unless-they-have-a-certain-description-in-th)

but there are no answers to that one either.

Comment: A google search found this: [An Introduction to Subversion Hook Scripts on Windows](http://blogs.wandisco.com/2011/11/10/an-introduction-to-subversion-hook-scripts-on-windows/)

Comment: Hi, I've dropped you an answer in your post on our forums here: http://www.wandisco.com/svnforum/threads/69110-Help-needed-with-a-Windows-SVN-hook-which-looks-for-a-certain-word-in-the-comment